How to construct a Map with conditional items with typescript
I want to add an item to a Map conditionally, and adding .filter but I'm getting         Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'readonly [string, Book]'.(2769). This is only issue when adding item conditionally and add .filter. How to construct a Map with conditional items?
type Book = {
  author: string,
  publishedDate: string,
}

const random = Math.random();

const booksMap = new Map<string, Book>([
  ['1', {
    author: 'Test',
    publishedDate: '2024-04-05'
  }],
  random > 0.5 ? ['1', {
    author: 'Test2',
    publishedDate: '2023-03-06'
  }] : null,
].filter(Boolean))

Demo
I tried to put the tuples outside the Map and filter them, and pass it to Map, but still it's same issue.

Use a function with a type guard instead of Boolean so that the inferred return type of filter is correct

The filter .filter(Boolean)) can cause some problems because TypeScript can detect when you are comparing against undefined and null; however, it is not as good at narrowing types down when comparing against other types.
You can use .filter(b => b !== null) instead:
type Book = {
  author: string,
  publishedDate: string,
}

const random = Math.random();

const books: (null|[string, Book])[] = [
  ['1', {
    author: 'Test',
    publishedDate: '2024-04-05'
  }],
  random > 0.5 ? ['2', {
    author: 'Test2',
    publishedDate: '2023-03-06'
  }] : null,
];

// (null|[string, Book])[] is narrowed down to [string, Book][]
const filteredBooks = books.filter(b => b !== null); 

const booksMap = new Map<string, Book>(filteredBooks);

This works in the latest version 5.5 thanks to Inferred Type Predicates. Here you can find more info about Inferred Type Predicates.

You might want to [edit] to add a link to ms/TS#50387 for the relevant feature request for filter(Boolean) to work.
